# Get Id of container by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the `id` of the containing div if I click on one of the `.row-settings` tool.

All the solutions I have tried just give me `undefined`

```html
<div id="content" class="container">
    <div class="ui-draggable">
        <div id="100" class="row clearfix template-block">
            <div class="column full" contenteditable="true">
                <div class="center">
                    <i class="icon ion-leaf size-48"></i>
                    <h1 style="font-size: 1.3em">BEAUTIFUL CONTENT</h1>
                    <div class="display">
                        <h1>LOREM IPSUM IS SIMPLY DUMMY TEXT 1</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px; display: block;">
            <div class="row-settings">
                Get Id
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-draggable">
        <div id="200" class="row clearfix template-block">
            <div class="column full" contenteditable="true">
                <div class="center">
                    <i class="icon ion-leaf size-48"></i>
                    <h1 style="font-size: 1.3em">BEAUTIFUL CONTENT</h1>
                    <div class="display">
                        <h1>LOREM IPSUM IS SIMPLY DUMMY TEXT 2</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px; display: block;">
            <div class="row-settings">
                Get Id
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-draggable">
        <div id="300" class="row clearfix template-block">
            <div class="column half" contenteditable="true">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus leo ante, consectetur sit amet vulputate vel, dapibus sit amet lectus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column half" contenteditable="true">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/300x150" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px;">
            <div class="row-settings">
                Get Id
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.row-settings').on('click',function(){
   id = $(this).parents('.template-block').attr('id')
   console.log(id)
});
```

I have made a fiddle (which is not working properly) so you will have the playground.

https://jsfiddle.net/5qfxzaph/

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `.template-block` is not a parent of `.row-settings`. It's a sibling.

Comment: Hoi @Andreas I don't understand your down vote. What you see in the fiddle is just one of the many attempt I have made to get this work. I have also tried sibling but without any success. It will be very useful for me if you will point me to the right direction

Comment: That's not my down-vote

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse up to ***ui-draggable***. In order to accomplish this you can use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then you can find the desired element:

```js
$('.row-settings').on('click',function(){
  id = $(this).closest('.ui-draggable').find('.template-block').attr('id')
  console.log(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="content" class="container">
    <div class="ui-draggable">
        <div id="100" class="row clearfix template-block">
            <div class="column full" contenteditable="true">
                <div class="center">
                    <i class="icon ion-leaf size-48"></i>
                    <h1 style="font-size: 1.3em">BEAUTIFUL CONTENT</h1>
                    <div class="display">
                        <h1>LOREM IPSUM IS SIMPLY DUMMY TEXT 1</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px; display: block;">
            <div class="row-settings">
                Get Id
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-draggable">
        <div id="200" class="row clearfix template-block">
            <div class="column full" contenteditable="true">
                <div class="center">
                    <i class="icon ion-leaf size-48"></i>
                    <h1 style="font-size: 1.3em">BEAUTIFUL CONTENT</h1>
                    <div class="display">
                        <h1>LOREM IPSUM IS SIMPLY DUMMY TEXT 2</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px; display: block;">
            <div class="row-settings">
                Get Id
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-draggable">
        <div id="300" class="row clearfix template-block">
            <div class="column half" contenteditable="true">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus leo ante, consectetur sit amet vulputate vel, dapibus sit amet lectus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column half" contenteditable="true">
                <img src="https://placehold.it/300x150" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px;">
            <div class="row-settings">
                Get Id
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.template-block` div is not a parent of `.row-settings` div . It's a sibling

```
 $(this).parents('.ui-draggable').find('.template-block')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the previous sibling of the parent div:

```js
$('.row-settings').on('click', function() {
  id = $(this).parent().prev().attr('id')
  console.log(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="container">
  <div class="ui-draggable">
    <div id="100" class="row clearfix template-block">
      <div class="column full" contenteditable="true">
        <div class="center">
          <i class="icon ion-leaf size-48"></i>
          <h1 style="font-size: 1.3em">BEAUTIFUL CONTENT</h1>
          <div class="display">
            <h1>LOREM IPSUM IS SIMPLY DUMMY TEXT 1</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px; display: block;">
      <div class="row-settings">
        Get Id
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-draggable">
    <div id="200" class="row clearfix template-block">
      <div class="column full" contenteditable="true">
        <div class="center">
          <i class="icon ion-leaf size-48"></i>
          <h1 style="font-size: 1.3em">BEAUTIFUL CONTENT</h1>
          <div class="display">
            <h1>LOREM IPSUM IS SIMPLY DUMMY TEXT 2</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px; display: block;">
      <div class="row-settings">
        Get Id
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-draggable">
    <div id="300" class="row clearfix template-block">
      <div class="column half" contenteditable="true">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus leo ante, consectetur sit amet vulputate vel, dapibus sit amet lectus.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column half" contenteditable="true">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x150" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px;">
      <div class="row-settings">
        Get Id
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't pointing to the correct parent. This should work:

```js
$('.row-settings').on('click',function(){
   id = $(this).parent().parent().find('.template-block').attr("id");
   console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="container">
 <div class="ui-draggable">
  <div id="100" class="row clearfix template-block">
   <div class="column full" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="center">
     <i class="icon ion-leaf size-48"></i>
     <h1 style="font-size: 1.3em">BEAUTIFUL CONTENT</h1>
     <div class="display">
      <h1>LOREM IPSUM IS SIMPLY DUMMY TEXT 1</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px; display: block;">
   <div class="row-settings">
    Get Id
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="ui-draggable">
  <div id="200" class="row clearfix template-block">
   <div class="column full" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="center">
     <i class="icon ion-leaf size-48"></i>
     <h1 style="font-size: 1.3em">BEAUTIFUL CONTENT</h1>
     <div class="display">
      <h1>LOREM IPSUM IS SIMPLY DUMMY TEXT 2</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px; display: block;">
   <div class="row-settings">
    Get Id
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="ui-draggable">
  <div id="300" class="row clearfix template-block">
   <div class="column half" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus leo ante, consectetur sit amet vulputate vel, dapibus sit amet lectus.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="column half" contenteditable="true">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x150" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-tool" style="right: auto; left: -37px;">
   <div class="row-settings">
    Get Id
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.template-block` is not a parent, so you need to get its parent element *first*, and then find the `template-block` to get the id.

```
id = $(this).parents('.ui-draggable').find('.template-block:first').attr('id');
```